# Why doe's facebook Graph Api not show all Hashtags

Tags: facebook, api, hashtag

for a client i try to get hashtags from the facebook api. I do this with a individual PHP script wich use the following link.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23hashtag&type=post&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

I use this with different hashtags and save the data json as ordert json to an own json file. After that i take the ordered json file and make my frontend output. This works very well.

But this is not my problem. The problem is the facebook api itself. When i am searching for an hashtag in Facebook i get other results than by trigger the same hashtag by Api request.

A lot of my searched hashtags are found in Facebook itself, but by api request i get for the same hashtag no data from the facebook api. Can anybody tell me what kind of workflow facebook have for his api data output?

Is it a question of relevance for hashtaged entrys on facebook? 
What can i do to get all entrys which i also have found by searching for hashtags in facebook?

I have tryed different searches from my script to different hashtags, sometimes it output a lot of entrys. For example "Berlin" or "Hamburg". But small hastags will not be found. For example "flower".

It would be very pleased if someone would have an answer to this.

best Peter

Comment: Just so you are aware of it post search is not available in API v2.0. So it will stop working at 4/30/2015

Answer (score 0):

This API is restricted to partners in the Public Content Solutions program. Learn more about the program and how you can apply [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/publiccontentsolutions/).